# how to Skill bar effect starts when scroll to the section?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, progress-bar

I made a beautiful Skill Bar and it works properly.
However, I just want my skill bar effect to start when I scroll to that section. For example: I am in my introduction section when I scroll down to the skill section it will trigger the effect.

Here is the code:

```js
;( function( $ ) {
    "use strict";

    $( ".bar" ).each( function() {

        var $bar = $( this ),
             $pct = $bar.find( ".pct" ),
             data = $bar.data( "bar" );

        setTimeout( function() {

            $bar
                .css( "background-color", data.color )
                .animate({
                    "width": $pct.html()
                }, data.speed || 1000, function() {

                    $pct.css({
                        "color": data.color,
                        "opacity": 1
                    });

                });

        }, data.delay || 0 );           

    });

})( jQuery );
```

```html
<ul id="skills">    
    <li>
        HTML5
        <div class="bar_container">
            <span class="bar" data-bar='{ "color": "#19f" }'>
                <span class="pct">82%</span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        CSS3
        <div class="bar_container">
            <span class="bar" data-bar='{ "color": "#27ae60", "delay": 600 }'>
                <span class="pct">100%</span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        PHP
        <div class="bar_container">
            <span class="bar" data-bar='{ "color": "#9b59b6", "delay": 1200 }'>
                <span class="pct">60%</span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        SQL
        <div class="bar_container">
            <span class="bar" data-bar='{ "color": "#ae8a33", "delay": 1800 }'>
                <span class="pct">30%</span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Demo: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9u0np8wv/1/)

Comment: use window.scroll

Answer (score 0):

You can check that the user scrolled the window to the bottom of the page and only then call the part of the code that start the animation:

```js
function animateSkillBars() {
  $( ".bar" ).each( function() {

          var $bar = $( this ),
               $pct = $bar.find( ".pct" ),
               data = $bar.data( "bar" );

          setTimeout( function() {

              $bar
                  .css( "background-color", data.color )
                  .animate({
                      "width": $pct.html()
                  }, data.speed || 1000, function() {

                      $pct.css({
                          "color": data.color,
                          "opacity": 1
                      });

                  });

          }, data.delay || 0 );           

      });
}

;( function( $ ) {
    "use strict";
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
            animateSkillBars();
        }
    });
    
})( jQuery );
```

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; outline: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
body { padding: 50px; background-color: #222; font-family: Arial; font-size: 14px; color: #ccc; }
ul { list-style-type: none; }

#skills {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 40%;
}

 #skills li {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
  padding-left: 6px;
 }

  .bar_container,
  .bar { 
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   height: 5px; 
   border-radius: 5px;
   content: "";
  }

  .bar_container {
   bottom: -8px;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: #333;
   text-align: right;
  }   

   .bar {
    top: 0;
   }

    .pct {
     position: absolute;
     top: -19px;
     right: 0;
     opacity: 0;
     transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit illum dolores fugit ut ratione quidem rem eveniet id, sapiente facilis maxime suscipit nostrum. Alias, voluptatum ipsa unde nemo magni atque!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit illum dolores fugit ut ratione quidem rem eveniet id, sapiente facilis maxime suscipit nostrum. Alias, voluptatum ipsa unde nemo magni atque!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit illum dolores fugit ut ratione quidem rem eveniet id, sapiente facilis maxime suscipit nostrum. Alias, voluptatum ipsa unde nemo magni atque!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit illum dolores fugit ut ratione quidem rem eveniet id, sapiente facilis maxime suscipit nostrum. Alias, voluptatum ipsa unde nemo magni atque!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit illum dolores fugit ut ratione quidem rem eveniet id, sapiente facilis maxime suscipit nostrum. Alias, voluptatum ipsa unde nemo magni atque!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit illum dolores fugit ut ratione quidem rem eveniet id, sapiente facilis maxime suscipit nostrum. Alias, voluptatum ipsa unde nemo magni atque!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit illum dolores fugit ut ratione quidem rem eveniet id, sapiente facilis maxime suscipit nostrum. Alias, voluptatum ipsa unde nemo magni atque!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit illum dolores fugit ut ratione quidem rem eveniet id, sapiente facilis maxime suscipit nostrum. Alias, voluptatum ipsa unde nemo magni atque!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit illum dolores fugit ut ratione quidem rem eveniet id, sapiente facilis maxime suscipit nostrum. Alias, voluptatum ipsa unde nemo magni atque!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit illum dolores fugit ut ratione quidem rem eveniet id, sapiente facilis maxime suscipit nostrum. Alias, voluptatum ipsa unde nemo magni atque!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit illum dolores fugit ut ratione quidem rem eveniet id, sapiente facilis maxime suscipit nostrum. Alias, voluptatum ipsa unde nemo magni atque!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit illum dolores fugit ut ratione quidem rem eveniet id, sapiente facilis maxime suscipit nostrum. Alias, voluptatum ipsa unde nemo magni atque!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit illum dolores fugit ut ratione quidem rem eveniet id, sapiente facilis maxime suscipit nostrum. Alias, voluptatum ipsa unde nemo magni atque!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit illum dolores fugit ut ratione quidem rem eveniet id, sapiente facilis maxime suscipit nostrum. Alias, voluptatum ipsa unde nemo magni atque!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit illum dolores fugit ut ratione quidem rem eveniet id, sapiente facilis maxime suscipit nostrum. Alias, voluptatum ipsa unde nemo magni atque!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit illum dolores fugit ut ratione quidem rem eveniet id, sapiente facilis maxime suscipit nostrum. Alias, voluptatum ipsa unde nemo magni atque!
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<ul id="skills"> 
 <li>
  HTML5
  <div class="bar_container">
   <span class="bar" data-bar='{ "color": "#19f" }'>
    <span class="pct">82%</span>
   </span>
  </div>
 </li>
 <li>
  CSS3
  <div class="bar_container">
   <span class="bar" data-bar='{ "color": "#27ae60", "delay": 600 }'>
    <span class="pct">100%</span>
   </span>
  </div>
 </li>
 <li>
  PHP
  <div class="bar_container">
   <span class="bar" data-bar='{ "color": "#9b59b6", "delay": 1200 }'>
    <span class="pct">60%</span>
   </span>
  </div>
 </li>
 <li>
  SQL
  <div class="bar_container">
   <span class="bar" data-bar='{ "color": "#ae8a33", "delay": 1800 }'>
    <span class="pct">30%</span>
   </span>
  </div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your code worked
But only if the scroll is completed :( , that means the user must scroll to the end of the page and then run the code.<br> your code : https://jsfiddle.net/bo3ggtx5/

Comment: You are correct. My answer is for your original question :) you are welcome to accept it. You can change this code based on your needs (instead of check the height of your page - check the position of the element that you want to be visible...)

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know programming, and my code belongs to someone else :(

Comment: well... stackoverflow is the place to get help, not for other people to solve your problems...

Comment: Please accept my apologies
I tried and I managed to fix the problem
But I found another problem with css
If you wish, you can help me by following the link below »: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45640187/why-text-blinking-in-my-style

Answer (score 0):

You can use `(window).scrollTop()` or just use a plugin [jquery appear](https://github.com/morr/jquery.appear)
through which you can track the element in the viewport

Comment: thanx
I tried but I have a problem
Please correct my code if possible - my code: https://jsfiddle.net/bo3ggtx5/