# Why is Text blinking in my style?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrolltop

After several hours and with the help of several people, I managed to solve the problem with the script.
But again, I found a problem with the style.
Where is my problem? Why does the relevant text blink?

```js
 var offsetTop = $('#skills').offset().top;
function animateSkillBars() {
  $( ".bar" ).each( function() {

          var $bar = $( this ),
               $pct = $bar.find( ".pct" ),
               data = $bar.data( "bar" );

          setTimeout( function() {

              $bar
                  .css( "background-color", data.color )
                  .animate({
                      "width": $pct.html()
                  }, data.speed || 10, function() {

                      $pct.css({
                          "color": data.color,
                          "opacity": 1
                      });

                  });

          }, data.delay || 0 );           

      });
}

;( function( $ ) {
    "use strict";
    $(window).scroll(function() {
    var height = $(window).height();
        if($(window).scrollTop()+height > offsetTop) {
            animateSkillBars();
        }
    });

})( jQuery );
```

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/bo3ggtx5/3/

Answer (score 3):

Its because you run the function everytime the `scrollTop` is bigger than the variable `offsetTop` you can add some class to check if you already run it for the bar or to wrapper div

https://jsfiddle.net/bo3ggtx5/4/

```
var offsetTop = $('#skills').offset().top;
function animateSkillBars() {
  $( ".bar" ).each( function() {

          var $bar = $( this ),
               $pct = $bar.find( ".pct" ),
               data = $bar.data( "bar" );

          if(!$(this).hasClass('animated')) {
            setTimeout( function() {

                $bar
                    .css( "background-color", data.color )
                    .animate({
                        "width": $pct.html()
                    }, data.speed || 10, function() {

                        $pct.css({
                            "color": data.color,
                            "opacity": 1
                        });

                    });

            }, data.delay || 0 );           
          }

          $(this).addClass('animated');
      });
}

;( function( $ ) {
    "use strict";
    $(window).scroll(function() {
    var height = $(window).height();
        if($(window).scrollTop()+height > offsetTop) {
            animateSkillBars();
        }
    });

})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a boolean `animated` variable to check if it's been animated once seems to fix the issue of flashing text. Looks like your text is updated every-time the user scrolls, which is causing the text to flash.

HTML:

```
<li>
    PHP
    <div class="bar_container">
        <span class="bar" data-bar='{ "color": "#9b59b6", "delay": 1200, "animated": false}'>
            <span class="pct">60%</span>
        </span>
    </div>
</li>
```

JavaScript:

```
function animateSkillBars() {
    $( ".bar" ).each( function() {

       var $bar = $( this ),
           $pct = $bar.find( ".pct" ),
           data = $bar.data( "bar" );

       if (!data.animated) {
          setTimeout( function() {
               $bar
                  .css( "background-color", data.color )
                  .animate({"width": $pct.html()
              }, data.speed || 10, function() {

                  $pct.css({
                      "color": data.color,
                      "opacity": 1
                  });

              });
             data.animated = true;      
          }, data.delay || 0 );
      }
  });
}

;( function( $ ) {
    "use strict";
    $(window).scroll(function() {
    var height = $(window).height();
        if($(window).scrollTop()+height > offsetTop) {
            animateSkillBars();
        }
    });

})( jQuery );
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bo3ggtx5/8/

Comment: You are setting a global variable, which is dangerous because in the event that the elements are on different parts of the page, animating in any single one of them will disable animation of the rest, even if they have not been scrolled into view.

Comment: @Terry: When the `animateSkillBars()` function runs, all bars are animated. There is no "scrolled into view" factor.

Comment: Updated. Instead of a global boolean, using a JSON boolean associated with each object - whether the item is animated, which shouldn't cause any conflicts.